# Echo text only if MySQL value matches

Tags: php, mysql

I have two rows in my MySQL data that I would like to have code echoed only if the MySQL row data is equal to '1' (as opposed to '0').  Here's the code so far, which seems to have some severe errors:

```
$query = "SELECT 162, 164 FROM search WHERE title = $title";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if ($row["162"] = 1) {
           echo '<div id="162link">1.6.2</div>'; 
           }
        }
        if ($row["164"] = 1) {
           echo '<div id="162link">1.6.2</div>';
           }
        }
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

As it says in the code above the two rows are "162" and "164" in the database.

Comment: Heads up, `=` is used for assignment, `==` is used for checking values (lose), `===` is used for checking identity values (strict).

Comment: SELECT 162, 164 will return literally these values, not corresponding columns.

Comment: Check your braces with the `IF` statements

Comment: Your query is way off the mark. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-statement-query-data.aspx) and have another go.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if ($row["162"] == 1)
```

Instead of:

```
if ($row["162"] = 1)
```

and:

```
if ($row["164"] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried for you something like this if it gives you some idea:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "myusername";
$pass = "mypassword";
$database = "WorldEngine";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$title = "My Good News";
$query = "SELECT `162`, `164` FROM search WHERE title = '$title';";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if ($row["162"] == 1) {
           echo '<div id="162link' . $i . '">1.6.2</div>'; 
        }
        if ($row["164"] == 1) {
           echo '<div id="164link' . $i . '">1.6.4</div>';
        }
      $i++;
    }

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

The index $i is appended to the div ID in order to produce unique DOM element ID's in the HTML document. I would also suggest you to change your numerical column names into alphabet-starting names like c162, c164, ...

Hope this will help you.